# How to only pick the first matched row in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables A and B with one-to-many relationship.

For rows A1 and A2 in table A, the relationship is

```
A1 -> [B11, B12, B13]
A2 -> [B21, B22]
```

When I join A and B I get

```
A1,B11
A1,B12
A1,B13
A2,B21
A2,B22
```

Instead I want

```
A1,B11
A2,B21
```

What should I do? I don't know what this mapping is called.

Comment: Is the actual data numerically sortable? I.e. is `B11` always lower in numeric value than `B13`? In that case you could do a join, then group by column `A`  and do a `min` on column `B`.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements will allow us to work on things with minimal effort.  **DATABASES DO NOT KEEP `ORDER`**.  You must define what you mean by `first row`.

Comment: Sorting by primary key is good enough

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you on? Always tag for version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use analytics - see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions057.htm) or examples [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/first-value-and-last-value-analytic-function) eg

Tables

```
create table A ( c1 ) as
select 'A1' from dual union
select 'A2' from dual ;

create table B ( c1, c2 ) as
select 'A1', 'B11' from dual union
select 'A1', 'B12' from dual union
select 'A1', 'B13' from dual union
select 'A2', 'B21' from dual union
select 'A2', 'B22' from dual ;
```

When joining the tables, we get ...

```
SQL> select *
  2  from A join B on A.c1 = B.c1 ;

C1 C1 C2 
-- -- ---
A1 A1 B11
A1 A1 B12
A1 A1 B13
A2 A2 B21
A2 A2 B22
```

Use FIRST_VALUE (without joining the tables)

```
select unique
  c1
, first_value( c2 ) over ( partition by c1 order by c2 ) fv
from B ;

C1 FV 
-- ---
A1 B11
A2 B21
```